# Visual Studio Hangs After Cordova Run

Tags: visual-studio, cordova

My Visual Studio Enterprise Hangs after i build and run my Cordova Application. Take note that I have not done anything yet but create the app then run it.

I tried changing my CLI to: 5.3.3 but still gives the same problem.

My current CLI version is 6.1.2

Help

Comment: I am having the same problem and its very frustrating. Have you been able to resolve it?